# Android: expanding Submenu in DrawerMenu

Tags: android, material-design, submenu, drawerlayout, drawer

I want to implement a Drawermenu in my Android App with the Options:

1. Profile
2. Settings
3. Info

For the implementations of the Drawermenu there are plenty of tutorials and all are very clear, however I cannot find anything on adding a Submenu similar to this one in my Reddit app:

[image: With click on "My Subscriptions" the List of my Subscriptions expands]

With click on "My Subscriptions" the List of my Subscriptions expands.

Is this really this hard to realize?
**Any Idea or advice is appreciated**

I have the Drawer set up like this:

**Layout XML:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.simon.drawtest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        addDrawerItems();
    }
    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = {"Profile", "Settings", "Info"};
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace your ListView with an [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). This is a good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) to start.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you! this solved it perfectly for me. All I had to do is follow the Tutorial and then change my activity_main.xml so it is actually a Drawer and can be pulled from the left.
Even though I agree with what @cricket_007 said, this one solved it for me in minutes so I will flag it as the correct answer! Thanks again!